# Magento 2: Transnational email custom variables

Tags: magento2, module, transactional-mail

There is zero documentation on how to create a variable and attach it to `$order` or anything of the sort. In my case, I need to multiply a product variables and quantity variable and display them as another variable within the transnational email that gets sent out with a order.

Answer (score 0):

the variable that pass to order email template is in the file

```
vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender.php
```

https://drops.meetanshi.com/kKe3RY

you can get all the variable that pass to template here

Comment: Thank you, however it still doesn't answer my question. How would I add to the $order to show for qty the value based on a product attribute I have added and times it by the qty of the items sold. aka. if cases_per_pallet was the attribute and its 52 and they have 10 qty in the order to times it by 52 and display it in the transactional email. Thanks

Comment: order item is list out in the file vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\email\items.phtml

Comment: Gotcha, now where is the area to change the actual value of the field below qty in the email?